writing the resultant of two polynomials as a product of roots by degree considerations
This is exercise14.6.31(c) on page620 about "resultant" in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra, 3rd edition.
Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i,g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^mb_jx^j\in F[x]$. Then the resultant of $f,g\in F[x]$ is the following determinant:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 m\ \text{rows}\begin{cases}\\\\\\\\\\\\\end{cases}
 \\n\ \text{rows}\begin{cases}\\\\\\\\\\\\\end{cases}
 \end{aligned}
\left|\begin{matrix}
 a_n & a_{n-1} & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
  & a_n & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
  & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & a_0 \\
  & & & a_n & a_{n-1} & \cdots & a_1 & a_0 \\
 b_m & b_{m-1} & \cdots &b_1 & b_0 \\
  & b_m & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
  & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & b_0 \\
  & & & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & b_1 & b_0 \\
\end{matrix}\right|_{(n+m)\times(n+m)}=\text{R}(f,g).
$$
Denote the roots of $f(x)$ by $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ and the roots of $g(x)$ by $y_1,\cdots,y_m$. One can use the fact (this is exercise14.6.30(b) on page620) that
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \text{R}(f,g)&=r(x)f(x)+s(x)g(x)
 \\&=r(x)a_n\prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)+s(x)b_m\prod_{j=1}^m(x-y_j)
 \\&=h(x),
\end{aligned}
$$
for some $r(x),s(x)\in F[x]$, to show that $(x_i-y_j)$ divides $\text{R}(f,g)$ in $F(x_1,\cdots,x_n,y_1,\cdots,y_m)$ by taking $x=x_i$ in $h(x)$ for each $i\in[1,n]$. The authors ask me to conclude by degree considerations that
$$
\text{R}(f,g)=a_n^mb_m^n\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^m(x_i-y_j).
$$
But I do not know how to use degree considerations to complete this.
Remark: the question Looking for a proof that the resultant is the product of the differences of roots may do not help since I find that "degree considerations" has not been directly use in the answers, and the answerers always use Euclidean Algorithm.


Update: according to @Nick 's hints, this is my new idea:
Let $F_g[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ be the polynomial ring in $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ over the field extension $F_g=F(b_0,\cdots,b_m)/F$ for which contains all the coefficients $b_0,\cdots,b_m$ of $g(x)$. Similar definition for $F_f[y_1,\cdots,y_m]$ too.

Since $R(f,g)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $m$ in $a_0,\cdots,a_n$ and also a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ in $b_0,\cdots,b_m$, it is of the form
$$
R(f,g)=\sum_j c_j \left(\prod_{i=1}^n a_i^{m_{ij}}\right) \left(\prod_{i=1}^m b_i^{n_{ij}}\right) \in F[a_0,\cdots,a_n,b_0,\cdots,b_m]
$$
where $c_j\in F$, and for a fixed $j$ we have
$$
\begin{cases}
 \sum_{i=0}^nm_{ij}=m.\\\sum_{i=0}^mn_{ij}=n.
\end{cases}
$$
Then since $a_i/a_n=(-1)^{n-i}s_{n-i}^f$ where $s_{n-i}^f$'s are the elementary symmetry functions in the roots of $f$, in $F[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \left(\prod_{i=1}^n a_i^{m_{ij}}\right)
 &=\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\left(a_n(-1)^{n-i}s_{n-i}^f\right)^{m_{ij}}\right)
 \\&=a_n^m(-1)^k\prod_{i=1}^n\left(s_{n-i}^f\right)^{m_{ij}}
\end{aligned}
$$
for some integer $k$. And since $s_{n-i}^f$ is of degree at most $\deg_{F_g}s_n=\deg_{F_g}\prod_{i=1}^nx_i=n$, we see that
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \deg_{F_g}\prod_{i=1}^n\left(s_{n-i}^f\right)^{m_{ij}}
 &=\sum_{i=1}^nm_{ij}\cdot\deg_{F_g}s_{n-i}^f
 \\&\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^nm_{ij}\cdot n
 \\&=n\left(\sum_{i=1}^nm_{ij}\right)
 \\&=nm,
\end{aligned}
$$
say, the degree of $R(f,g)$ is at most $nm$ in $F_g[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, and similarly the degree of $R(f,g)$ is also at most $nm$ in $F_f[y_1,\cdots,y_m]$.

Consider the polynomial $h=\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^m(x_i-y_j)\in F[x_1,\cdots,x_n,y_1,\cdots,y_m]$. Since it is clearly a symmetry function in $y_1,\cdots,y_m$ by rewriting it as $h=\prod_{i=1}^n\big(g(x_i)/b_m\big)=b_m^{-n}\prod_{i=1}^ng(x_i)$, we can view it as a polynomial in $F_g[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. Then in $F_g[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, the term of largest degree in the product of $h$ is clearly $b_m^{-n}\prod_{i=1}^nx_i^m$, which is of degree $nm$, and so does $h$, denoting this by $\deg_{F_g}h=nm$. Similarly we have also that $\deg_{F_f}h=nm$.

Moreover, I have proved that $h$ divides $R(f,g)$ in $F[x_1,\cdots,x_n,y_1,\cdots,y_m]$ before updating, thus we must have $\deg_{F_g}R(f,g)\geqslant\deg_{F_g}h=nm$ in $F_g[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ and $\deg_{F_f}R(f,g)\geqslant\deg_{F_f}h=nm$ in $F_f[y_1,\cdots,y_m]$ respectively. But then $\deg_{F_g}R(f,g)\leqslant nm$ and $\deg_{F_f}R(f,g)\leqslant nm$ imply that $u\big(b_m^{-n}\prod_{i=1}^ng(x_i)\big)=uh=R(f,g)$ and $v\big((-1)^{nm}a_n^{-m}\prod_{i=1}^mf(y_i)\big)=vh=R(f,g)$ for some $u\in F_g$ and some $v\in F_f$, respectively. In fact $F_g=F_f=F$ since $a_0,\cdots,a_n,b_0,\cdots,b_m\in F$. Thereby $ch=R(f,g)$ for some $c\in F$, namely $c\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^m(x_i-y_j)=R(f,g)$.
But it seems to make nonsense since I have no ideas to show that the quotient of $R(f,g)$ by $\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^m(x_i-y_j)$ is exactly $a_n^mb_m^n$ yet. Once I multiply $a_n^mb_m^n\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^m(x_i-y_j)$ by a constant $c$ in $F$ the resulting polynomial $c\,a_n^mb_m^n\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^m(x_i-y_j)$ will not change its degree in $a_i$'s or in $b_j$'s, so how can we make sure that $c=1$? This is the difficulty, I think.

@CalvinLin thanks for pointing out my typo, I have corrected it.

Here, "by degree considerations" means to find the degree of $R(f, g)$, count how many factors of $R(f, g)$ you've already identified, and show that these match. If another factor exists, then $R(f, g)$'s degree is higher than what you know it is which is a contradiction.
The problem says to consider each $a_i$ as $a_i = (-1)^{n-i} a_n s_{n-i}$, where $s_\ell(x_0, ..., x_n)$ is the $\ell$-th elementary symmetric function of the roots $x_0, x_1, …$, and similarly for the $b_j$. You are supposed to show that $R(f, g)$ is a homogenous polynomial of degree $m$ in the $a_i$, and degree $n$ in the $b_j$, and then you can apply the above reasoning.

Addition: The hints above get us to the point where we know
$$R(f, g) = c\prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{j=1}^m (x_i - y_j)$$
for some constant $c$ that can't include any $x_i$ or $y_j$. To finish we need to show $c = a_n^m b_m^n$.
In $R(f, g)$, we can replace each $a_i$ by $(-1)^{n-i} a_n s_{n-i}$ as before. Notice that all of the terms of the elementary symmetric functions $s_\ell$ are just products of roots $x_i$ without any other factors, so the symmetric functions do not contribute anything to $c$ and can be ignored. Since $R(f, g)$ is homogenous as a function of the $a_i$, every term of $R(f, g)$ will contain the factor $a_n^m$ times some $s_\ell$ and a sign. Applying the same logic to the $b_j$, we have a factor $b_m^n$ in every term. Combining the two gives $c = a_n^m b_m^n$.
There's just one thing that should be checked which is the sign. Expanding the product formula for $R(f, g)$ that we are trying to prove, the final term is $ a_n^m b_m^n \, (-1)^{mn} y_0^n ... y_m^n$ which we notice is equal to $a_n^m ((-1)^m b_m y_0...y_m)^n = a_n^m b_0^n$. On the other hand, when expanding the determinant version of the formula, the term that comes from multiplying along the main diagonal is precisely $a_n^m b_0^n$. You can check that no other term of the determinant expansion can have $n$-th degree in all $y_j$ and degree $0$ in all $x_i$, so the sign of this term in one formula must match the sign in the other. In fact, the signs do match, so the product formula is already correct and we are done.

Thanks! Could you tell me that the usage of "homogeneous", I have just proved it but do not know how to use it.

$R(f,g)$ can be written as a homogenous polynomial in terms of the $a_i$ and $b_j$ but that isn’t the important part, what is important is that every $a_i$ term has degree $m$ or less, and this implies every $x_i$ term has degree $m$ or less, and so on.

That first $a_n^m b_m^n$ part of the formula does come from the fact that they are homogenous though, because when you write out $R(f,g)$ you get exactly $m$ factors of $a_n$ in each term, etc.

According to your first comment I have already made an update. But I still have no ideas to show that the quotient of $R(f,g)$ by $\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^m(x_i-y_j)$ is exactly $a_n^mb_m^n$ yet. Once I multiply $a_n^mb_m^n\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^m(x_i-y_j)$ by a constant $c$ in $F$ the resulting polynomial $c,a_n^mb_m^n\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^m(x_i-y_j)$ will not change its degree in $a_i$'s or in $b_j$'s, so how can we make sure that $c=1$? This is the difficulty, I think.

@QuayChern I updated with more details on this part of it

I get it! Thanks for your help, have a nice day!
